# Ruby on Rails Routing Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a website where users can sell tickets to their events. Tickets being sold for events are going to be promoted by promoters. In turn, the client wants a unique url that a promoter can email out to potential customers to sell tickets to.  Thus, I have to create a unique url that includes the promoters unique code along with an event id (To track sales).  The problem I am having is figuring out how to create this unique url. There's a many-to-many relationship between Event and Promoter joined together by a Promotion table.  The Promotion table will track each event's promoters as well as have an attribute to store how many tickets sold. In the Promoter table I will store basic information, such as name, along with the unique code the system will generate.

I know I can create a named route that can find an Event by id or a Promoter by id. The problem is I need to have the Event Id in the url along with the promoters unique code (unless there's a better way to do this). I will then be able to write a query to find an Event with a condition of the Promoter's unique code.

Any thoughts on how I might accomplish this? I think what is stumping me is that there is two parameters in the url.

Update:

```
map.buy_ticket 'buy_ticket/:id_1/:id_2',
 :controller => :events,
 :action => :buyTicket,
 :id_1 => /\d+/,
 :id_2 => /[a-z]+[0-9]+/i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer at your own question. When I the share link to this question, here's what I have:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7102231/293686
```

The number **7102231** is your question id and **293686** is my user id, so, when I share this question somewhere else SO knows it was me that did it, which is the same thing you're trying to do, just create a route that contains both ids and you're done.

Comment: I updated my post. The code at the bottom is that how I would set this up?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the case, but please use :promoter_id and :event_id at your URL so the code is well documented.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: These routes are for Rails 3.  I probably should have asked what version you were using first :-)

Is Promotion a join table between Events and Promoters?  If that's the case you could simply use the Promotion resource to track both.

If that's not the case, multiple params in a route is a simple matter handled in several ways.

You could nest resources, e.g.

```
resources :events do
  resources :promotions
end

# which would result in urls like /events/:event_id/promotions/:id
```

Or you could map them yourself like

```
get "/events/:event_id/promos/:promoter_code", :to => "events#show"

# Which would manually map the route to events_controller#show, passing along your 
# event id and a unique promoter code.  Just an example, but you get the idea.
```

Comment: The update is going to be the answer I'm afraid.  This is using the new routing DSL which was introduced with Rails 3. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can create routes by hand in pretty much whatever format you need. Something like this in your `routes.rb`:

```
match '/ticket/:promoter_id:/:event_id' => 'controller#method', :via => :get, :as => :route_name
```

Then you'll have `:promoter_id` and `:event_id` in your `params` when `method` is called. This will also give you `route_name_path` and `route_name_url` helpers.

The `ticket`, `controller`, `method`, and `:route_name` are, of course, just placeholders for demonstration purposes.

The [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes) has further details.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a non-resourceful route:

```
get 'event/:id/promotion/:unique_code' => 'event#promotion', :as => 'event_promotion'
```

and the url will be `event/32/promotion/AEBCDE` with the event_id being 32 and promotion code as 'AEBCDE'